# Split single argument in multiple parts

Tags: macros

I would like to define the command `A\!\!_B\!C` in a math mode as a macros, and I am using the following:

`\newcommand{\cmp}[3]{#1\!\!_#2\!#3}`

Unfortunately I get an error that there are `{}` missing. Any hint is appreciated.

Is there any possibility to get a Mathematica-like syntax with only one argument, splitting it a the comma?

Comment: At least it should be `\newcommand{\cmp}{...}` with a backslash.

Comment: I don't get any error once I add @egreg's backslash...

Comment: You might also want to use _{#2} in case #2 has more than one character.

Comment: @egreg: I had that in code, didn't copy properly here. Could you clarify how shall I call \cmp then in the body?

Comment: @Ilya Can you make a simple example of what gives you an error?

Comment: @egreg: I guess, I've found the reason - worked to much with Mathematica and was calling \cmp{A,B,C} instead of \cmp{A}{B}{C}. I guess I shall delete this question - unlikely it is valuable to other users.

Comment: If you would like the syntax different, for your convenience, you could refine the question.  e.g., `\cmp{A B C}`, `\cmp{A,B,C}`, etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: do you mean I can write `\cmp{A, B, C}` instead of `\cmp{A}{B}{C}`?

Comment: You can't write it that way using the standard LaTeX interface, unless special code is written to accept it that way.  But if that is what would be preferable for you to input, you could rephrase the question to ask if a routine could be written to accept that particular syntax.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I see your point, thanks. I think so far I'm fine with the usual syntax, I use this expression often enough to express it as a macros, but rare enough to do more coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
\def\cmp#1{\cmpA#1,}
\def\cmpA#1,#2,#3,{{#1}\!\!_{#2}\!{#3}}

$a = \cmp{A,B,C}$
```

But I don't understand, why do you need the ugly clump of letters.

Comment: I've been asking myself the same question. But look at how old the queston is, i  bet we will never here the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With your original command you have to remember to give it three arguments.

With package `xparse` you can split one argument at a given symbol (here the comma) and hence stick with the syntax you know from Mathematica.

The output looks a little bit odd though, but this is a different matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\cmp}[3]{#1\!\!_{#2}\!#3}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmpA}{  >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}} m}
{\cmp#1}%<- feeding the three arguments to the original command

\begin{document}
\[ \cmp{A}{B}{C} \]
\[ \cmpA{A,B,C} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg I changed it for the sake of generity. I thought about it as well (it is also above in the comments), but decided against it as there is some kind of logic behind that *thing* (at least i hope so).